Content Security Policy when clients access via Windows Remote Desktop
Have django-csp working in report only mode on application deployed on aws using gunicorn/nginx. No reported issues in dev or prod except when clients log into their work computers to work remotely. Using a secured remote desktop session (I can recreate accessing production web using browser running in vm). I get nothing but errors and warnings about hosted page injection.
Now my understanding is that CSP is meant to protect against unauthorized CSS but are there settings or headers that will allow site to operate in an approved remote window.
Any guidance is appreciated.

Without much detail here...can you please share your ALLOWED_HOSTS attribute from your settings.py? Actually, please show the whole settings.py...my take based on what you've posted is that when someone attempts to access the app from a domain/IP not "allowed" from ALLOWED_HOSTS is why you are getting an issue. It could also be CORS in my experience, but if you can run it in your created VM then, I think it is an Allowed Host issue...but would appreciate seeing your whole settings file and perhaps what IP/URL your users are hitting errors from.

It does not work in vm. Allowed hosts is just the website domain name in production. They are logging into this website regardless of remote desktop or not. Wouldn't django simply fail before csp error if allowed hosts were not matching?

Not sure how you have your system setup to run as you show no code, so I can't provide real feedback that might be helpful, please post settings and configs of your VM, I'm sure this is simple but without much more info, I (at least) don't know if I can help

This eventually was determined to be a cache issue. The solution ending up being  a cache busting set of tasks involving hashing contents so that all of the new csp compliant code was always used.
